# Using EF's Enum's in Lightswitch in ComboBox/DropDown list control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have created the following tables:

[image]

The **Role** in the AccountContact table is the following enum:

```
public enum UserRoles : int
{
    Admin = 0,
    AccountAdmin = 1,
    AccountUser = 2,
    SiteAdmin = 3,
    SiteUser = 4,
    User = 5,
    None = 6
}
```

In Lightswitch, I've added the database created from the EF design but the Role is int in the data-source table and not the enum.  How do I create the drop-down for lightswitch of the enum and selection to be the resulting int?

Comment: Have you tried converting Role to the enum type in the EF model? Rigtclick on the Role and use "Convert to Enum". You can use then an external enum type. I blogged about this here http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/09/11/using-exisiting-enum-types-in-entity-framework-5/

Comment: @Pawel I did that already, `The Role in the AccountContact table **is** the following enum`

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear to me from the description.

Answer (score 0):

Even though EF5 now supports enums, that doesn't automatically mean that LightSwitch also supports them.

I'm not using LS 2012 yet, so I can't confirm this, but it's likley to be your problem. I don't remember hearing that enum support had been introduced into LightSwitch.

Comment: That is what I'm thinking - unless I use a RIA service for EF5 to handle the Data and LS to just handle the front end.  I could use Choice Lists perhaps as well.

Comment: For enum-type data I actually use a lookup table (id, value). I also use an enum in code, that corresponds to the values in the table.